# Will it not be a good idea to take off the daily reputation limit?

Tags: feature-request, daily-reputation-limit, discussion

I have seen some other questions discussing or requiring that the daily reputation limit is wished to be no more. One which seems popular enough is the following:

**[Please get rid of daily reputation limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1466/please-get-rid-of-daily-reputation-limit)**

1. Has this been done already?
2. Will it not be a good idea to take if off our path as SO's contributors?
3. Is this feature on its way, will it ever be put into production on the live SO site?

I do not wish to duplicate the question, although it looks alike. I'm only wondering whether the SO developers who, let me say have done a great work, have created the community are working on it or if we can hope to see this limit rid someday.

I can't imagine what Jon Skeet's reputation would look like without it from the beginning, though! =P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it has not already been completed and it will not be completed anytime in the future as indicated by the status-declined tag on that question.

Comment: I had not noticed the `[status-declined]` tag, sorry. =)

Answer (score 1):

> Has this been done already?

No, and it's unlikely to happen.

However, there is a query  to find out a user's reputation as if there were no reputation cap [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42121/is-there-a-script-tool-to-calculate-the-rep-as-if-there-were-no-cap) (and now on OData [here](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/15825/how-much-rep-would-i-have-were-there-no-rep-cap?UserId=22656), replace the UserID by yours).

Jon Skeet would have a whopping 642,928 points if there were no rep cap - instead of his current 245,400.

Comment: That sounds like an excellent reason to remove the rep cap, from my point of view :) Given Nick Craver's uncapped rep (~145K vs 118K capped) it would also make it less likely for him to catch up with me. Maybe just a higher rep cap (500 per day?) would be enough...

Comment: @Jon I can see your point of view! :) Well, arguably, you *would* deserve it - as far as a cursory glance shows, your "excess rep" ratio is *way* higher than anybody else's on page 1. That can partly be explained by rep gain on past answers, but not just. On the other hand, the way SO's user numbers are developing, removing the reputation cap would have a serious impact on productivity in the IT industry across the globe :)