# Add the ability to view the reputation as if there was no rep cap

Tags: feature-request, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, reputation-recalc

Add a place to view the total reputation a user would have achieved if there was no rep cap (daily-reputation-limit).  It would be a good measure to see who are the ones that answer even if they have reached the rep cap.

Comment: Why would we care about that? What would you do with the information? How would this improve the site?

Comment: It would encourage people to answe even if they have reached the rep cap, I suggest to put it a place (Not in the profile directly)

Comment: We already have top-20 user lists per tag, where you users ranked by total score for both questions and answers for that tag. That's plenty of info to compare users that give the best answers in an area.

Comment: I won't add any meta question ever, you have nothing to do except downvoting :(

Comment: You just happen to ask for things that are not really needed. Please don't take it personally and don't let it stop you from suggesting new ideas.

Comment: @MohammadSakherSawan Most users I know who regularly hit the rep cap are not stopped by that to begin with. They tend to be fairly active far beyond the cap. And on the rare occasions that I hit the cap here on Meta, I keep on answering regardless. I don't think this proposal adds all that much. And what's with this *"I won't add any Meta question ever"*? If you make a feature request, you can't expect it to go without any questions or discussion.

Comment: Your question isn't very constructive, it doesn't identify a real need for your feature request. Is there an actual lack of answers from people reaching the rep cap? When reaching the rep cap, you still get points from your answer being accepted. Looking at the [reputation ranks](http://stackoverflow.com/users) on SO I see plenty of people going well over 200 points, so they are clearly not demotivated by the rep cap.

Comment: @MohammadSakherSawan: See the [META-FAQ#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites. People are not (just) voting on the quality of your question, they are also voting on the proposal itself. Thus a downvote could mean: "I don't think this feature request should be implemented".

Comment: Thank you all, I am sorry, I will keep trying to make stackoverflow better, but I am very disappointed, yesterday I have got 20+ down votes for a feature request is not very useful.

Comment: Thanx @MartijnPieters, I see the point

Comment: Meta rep means nothing. I've got 18k+ at the moment and it doesn't buy me anything. (I keep trying to get Starbucks to accept it, but they won't) Don't get too worked up over it. You win some, you lose some. Especially with downvotes sometimes being used to indicate disagreement here on Meta.

Comment: Don't worry about your reputation on Meta, it's largely useless here anyway. :-)

Comment: @Bart, You mean that you won't block me if I have big downvotes for some question :)

Comment: @MohammadSakherSawan I can guarantee you that **I** won't block you. Because I as a user don't have that power. (Nor would I want to block you at all). But the automatic post-ban rules here on Meta seem to be far more relaxed than on the main site. If you don't have a significant number of highly downvoted questions/proposals, you won't be in any danger.

Comment: That said, next time you make a feature request, think of a couple of things. "How does it improve the site?", "Is the effort it will take the developers worth it?", "Is there a real need for this?", "What problem does it solve?", "Has this been proposed before in any form?". Etc. Once you can convincingly answer these questions for yourself, you have a far better idea of whether or not it's worth the request and how it might go over.

Comment: Related: [Is there a script/tool to calculate the rep as if there were no cap?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42121)

Answer (score 4):

You can see this leaderboard already on SE Data Explorer [ranked by uncapped reputation](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/89793/105936/top-rated-users-if-there-was-no-reputation-cap) and [ranked by lost reputation potential](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/84762/top-rated-users-if-there-was-no-reputation-cap).

[You can use this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/89791/105934/top-rated-users-if-there-was-no-reputation-cap) if you want to check the stat for any given person.

Apparently, Jon Skeet would have above 1,742,966.

Comment: Just one note, the data there is not live. Looking in the results they appear to be about three days old according to the reputation, however according to the Data Explorer [faq page](http://data.stackexchange.com/faq): "How frequently is Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated? Data is updated monthly."

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Actually, perhaps that FAQ is out of date. I think it is [updated weekly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/when-will-data-se-get-updated-data/145732#145732).

Comment: @Bart yep good point, I left comment for Nick to fix this.

Comment: Merry Christmas Nick.... ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/3344/waffle-vote-counter) for calculating what I call "waffle" rep (the rep you don't get because of the cap).

Try it!